# Installing on Snow Leopard?

Tags: 10.10, dual-boot, installation, mac, refit

Have Snow Leopard 10.6.5 on a working MacBook Pro. Have CD of Ubuntu 10.10 amd.dmg in the CD drive. Have rEFIt. Now what?

Comment: I believe you need the alternate install cd in order to get EFI support, I may be wrong

Answer (score 1):

I thought all Macs were intel, not amd... anyway follow the guide here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook

Please try and ask only concise, specific questions and not open ended questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try partitioning your drive with BootCamp and just use the Ubuntu CD instead of the Windows CD to install from.